# How to remove all non-digits from a string in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Users input numbers in the following forms:

```
1-800-432-4567
800-432-4567
800.432.4566
(800)432.4567
+1(800)-432-4567
800 432 4567
```

I want all of these to be turned into a stripped version without the special characters like `18004324567`. The data come in the form of a `String`, so string checking isn't required.

My method is as below:

```
def canonical_form number
  a = remove_whitespaces number #to clear all whitespaces in between
  a.gsub(/[()-+.]/,'')     
end

def remove_whitespaces number
  number.gsub(/\s+/,'')  #removes all whitespaces
end
```

Is there a better way to do this? Can the white space check with the regular expression in `canonical_form` method be performed without having an extra method for white spaces? How can this be refactored or done in a neater way?

Comment: Try `number.gsub(/\D/, '')` to remove all non-digits.

Comment: [`number.gsub(/\D+/, '')`](https://regex101.com/r/uD1eU7/1)

Comment: By tagging your question with regex or writing gsub in the title, you are limiting the answers.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If the first argument of the `tr` method of String starts with `^`, then it denotes all characters except those listed.

```
def canonical_form str
  str.tr('^0-9', '')   
end
```

Comment: or `str.delete('^0-9')`

Answer (score 55):

Several solutions above - I benchmarked a few in case anyone is interested:

```
str = "1-800-432-4567"
Benchmark.ms { 10000.times{str.scan(/\d/).join} }
#=> 69.4419999490492 

Benchmark.ms { 10000.times{str.delete('^0-9')} }
#=> 7.574999995995313 

Benchmark.ms { 10000.times{str.tr('^0-9', '')} }
#=> 7.642999989911914

Benchmark.ms { 10000.times{str.gsub(/\D+/, '')} }
#=> 28.084999998100102
```

Comment: I know this is a little late but thanks for doing this.

Comment: Love that the simplest solution is also the fastest...

Answer (score 4):

Instead of removing special characters, you can looks for all digits. Something like:

```
str = "1-800-432-4567"
str.scan(/\d/).join
#=> "18004324567"

str = "(800)432.4567"
str.scan(/\d/).join
#=> "8004324567"
```