# Remove dollar sign and comma from price in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a simple model with a decimal column

```
class CreateCourses < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :courses do |t|
      t.decimal :fee, precision: 12, scale: 2
    end
  end
end


class Course < ApplicationRecord
  validates :fee,  presence: true, numericality: { greater_than: 1, less_than: 1000 }
end


<%= simple_form_for @course do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :fee %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

How do I remove the dollar sign if a user enters it in the form? Currently it gives me this error `Fee can't be blank and Fee is not a number`. I tried the following but it gives me another error `undefined method delete for 0.5e1:BigDecimal`

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  validates :fee,  presence: true, numericality: { greater_than: 1, less_than: 1000 }
  
  before_validation :clean_fee
    
  private 
  def clean_fee
    self.fee = fee.delete('$ ,')
  end
end
```

Comment: Probably what you're after: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35603532/how-to-remove-all-non-digits-from-a-string-in-ruby.

Comment: Meh, I'm dense. ``fee`` is already a number when ``before_validation`` runs, which is why you are getting the error on ``.delete``. Likely there is an issue with the validation format; I'll try to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `’$5,123’.gsub(/[^0-9\.]/, '')` in my app for costs and quantities and it works fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier, if the user couldn't enter a $-sign?

You can use regex and limit the input to numbers and decimals:

(\d+.\d+|\d+|.\d+)

Answer (score -1):

Since your fee column is a datatype `decimal`, I think you should use an number field instead of a textfield. Changing your `<%= f.input :fee %>` to `<%= f.number_field :fee %>` would do the trick.

Comment: that didn't work.... now if a user enters 5.00 it gives the error `undefined method delete for 0.5e1:BigDecimal` and if the user enters $5.00 it gives the error `undefined method delete for nil:NilClass`

Comment: The errors is because your validation still wants to remove the $ sign. You need to turn off that validation to make it work.